# How to define Property range.formula for two dimensional array

Tags: vba, excel, properties, formula

I'm wondering if someone can explain how property range.formula works in more detail then vba basic help.

I would like to use this property to test if all cells are empty in range. (I know and I can type a plenty of other codes how to test it but I would like to find way how to do using this property).

So for example if I want to check all cell in range("A1:A10") I've only done it like this.

```
    Private Sub cell_in_range()
Dim i As Integer
Dim iTest As Integer

  i = 1
  Do While i <= 10 And iTest = 0
  iTest = VBA.Len(Sheet17.Range("A" & i).Formula)
    If iTest > 0 Then
    Call VBA.MsgBox("Not all cells empty")
    End If

    i = i + 1
  Loop

  If VBA.Len(shee17.Range("A" & i)) = 0 Then
  Call VBA.MsgBox("All cells empty")
  End If


End Sub
```

This works but what if I would like to check in this way for example range of cells range("A1:X1000") 
Again I know that instead of range I can you nested do while loops and change cells index like cells(i,j)
but again I would like to do it using property range.formula

I spent an hours to google how to define formula for two dimensional array. Can anybody explain this topic in more detail.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are just trying to count the empty cells, `Range` has a property called `SpecialCells`, which you can select blank cells with.  This formula will calculate the number of blank cells in the range `A1:A100`: `Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count`. You can adjust those ranges as necessary.

Comment: Hello Bruce, Yes I know this property.But I'm asking because I think I would like to do in this way using property formula. But thanks for the answer

Comment: (There's also the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`, does that help?)

Comment: You need to specify **exactly** what you mean by *'all cells are empty'*. Do the cells contain formulas that may be returning zero-length strings? Do the 'non-empty' cells contain text, numbers or a combination of both? Is the data an import (possibly from a web page) that may contain zero-length strings, spaces, non-breaking spaces, etc that may *look* blank while not actually being blank?

Comment: I think you may be working on an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clarify your overall goal with the sub? Are you simply trying to find empty cells? Or cells with just a formula?  It looks like you're testing if a `Formula` is over `1` character long...

Comment: I just would like to understand how .formula property works or at least find some detail documentation. Since vba is object programing langue object range has a property formula. As I've type in to the question I haven't found any sensible documentation to understand it so I try to demonstrate it on some problem.
So I'm trying to understand how this property works? So it's more object programing question rather than how to do something.

Comment: Have you read through the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)? Or any of the [Google results](https://www.google.com/#q=.formula+property+vba)?

Comment: Maybe it looks like not, But I've spent several hours to find more deep documentation. When I'll find the answer I'll post it and you will understand why I have asked here in this complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

Is this of any help ??

```
Sub formulatest()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:X1000")

    For Each r In rng
        If r.HasFormula Then
            MsgBox "cell " & r.Address & " has a formula"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "no cells have formulas"
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

You don't need loops.  For the range **A1:B2**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:B2")

    arr = rng.Formula

    For Each a In arr
        MsgBox a
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Not really. 
Since .formula is the property of range you would be able to define this also using do while loop (so without for loop). This question is more in to the understanding of excel object model

Comment: @PavolNamer - Can you please (in your OP), clarify what *exactly* you're trying to learn/find out? Are you looking for a practical answer, or a discussion on the `.Formula` property of the `Range`? I assume you've read over the [Microsoft info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I did and can't find more detail documentation for .formula property. Just want to find more deep documentation to fully understand this property. Thanks

Comment: @PavolNamer  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I don't think he's asking for a VBA/Formula solution here. I don't quite know what OP is looking for, but I think it's just detail on the `.Formula` property?  What detail, or for what specific idea, I can't quite tell.

Comment: @BruceWayne  Do you recommend that I delete this Answer ??

Comment: Ah, no! I was just commenting. I can't quite get the nuance of what OP is asking, but you give a nice answer for avoiding the error OP is getting (and possibly, teaching OP how to loop through cells).  From reading the OP's question though, this *should* answer it ("..what if I would like to check in this way for example range of cells range("A1:X1000") ...")...?

Answer (score 0):

the .formula property is used to set or return the formula contained in a specific range. if the range contains multiple cells the property returns a bidimensional array.

I would use the following instruction

```
Application.Count(Range("A1:X1000"))
```

if it returns 0, all cells are empty.

Comment: Hello, thank you.
I know that I can test it in many different ways but I'm trying to understand property formula.
I try to ask you in different question: 
What if I would like to output (in vba.msgBox) the first formula expression in range of cells range("A1:X1000")
let's say only cell B14 has some formula in it and other cells in this range are empty.
Thank you

Comment: in this case the property .formula will return an array. the content of cell B14 would be at (1,13) or (2,14)